# SimpleAdapter and ContextMenu

Tags: android, contextmenu, simpleadapter

Hello my fellow Droid Developers! I have a problem that's been kicking my butt for a while now. I'm hoping someone can help me so I can move forward with the learn'n.

I'm having trouble connecting a ContextMenu to my SimpleAdapter. I've done extensive searches but cannot find or "connect the dots" to solve this problem. I'm not doing anything fancy with the simpleadapter nor the ContextMenu.

My setup seems correct because the listview's onListItemClick returns the ID I've loaded into the list so I know everything is properly setup.

This is a public class which extends ListActivity

Here's what i have so far...

My ROW.xml The list loads fine here

```
...<ListView
android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="No data"/>
```

SimpleAdapter snippet. This works fine.

```
 SimpleAdapter notes = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            resourceNames,
            R.layout.list_question_row,
            new String[] { "qid", "line1","line2", "img", "img2" },
            new int[] { R.id.question_id, R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.img, R.id.img2 } );
    ;
    setListAdapter( notes );
```

Here's where things break down. I can't seem to figure out how to hook up the setOnCreateContextMenuListener to the SimpleAdapter / ListView.

Also, the R.id.list is not being picked up by Eclipse. I've tried switching the layout XML's ID to @android:id/list but that didn't seem to work either. I can't seem to get a reference to the ID of the ListView list.

```
    setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener(){
    @Override 
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,  ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
     if (v.getId()==R.id.list) {  
         AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;  
         menu.setHeaderTitle("Action Menu");  
         menu.add(0, MENU_EDIT, 0, "Edit");  
         menu.add(0, MENU_DELETE, 0,  "Delete");
    }  
 }; //end of onCreateContextMenu
```

I hope this is something simple to solve! Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `R.id.list`, try `android.R.id.list`.

Comment: That's just crazy! All the hours I've spent looking for a solution and never saw that used. Thank you very much Matt!